# Design question for a Java Application

Tags: design-patterns

I am asking a design question .

Assume that there is a class in the Application (Where all the requests go through this particular class)

Could anybody  please tell me whether it is good to make this particular class as Singleton or not ??

Comment: I strongly urge you to provide more detail.  There is not enough information to say definitively if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: I have an undescribed program, should I use the singleton pattern is impossible to answer.

Comment: It's likely a better idea to get rid of your god class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this class have properties like DB connection info, or other "global" settings, it's a good idea to think it as a Singleton Class. Other benefit is that if the class is Singleton, you don't need to instantiate it every time you need it, there will be just only one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you create a new instance for every request that comes to that class. Do you expect a large number of simultaneous requests completely overwhelming your system (due to the creation of a large number of objects)?

Another point of consideration is whether this class shares some common resources among the requests (you might also want to think of contention issues here)